# Need recent (Dec-2015) Makefile stub for native Android binary compilation

Tags: android, makefile, android-ndk

I would like to compile C & C++ code for native use on an Android phone.  I have the NDK and I managed to build and run a simple hello_world.c, but I had to pull startup files (crtbegin_dynamic.o, crtend_android.o) into my build directory and I think my -I and -L directories are fragile (I hard-coded android versions, architectures, and so forth).

Is there a simple Makefile stub that sets a few variables so that the NDK Makefiles can work correctly for building a native binary?  All the examples and instructions seem to be designed to build a combined Java/native app, or a native library called from Java, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it...I'm still unhappy about the path to the compiler, but you could fix it by putting that directory on your $PATH.

```
#
# Makefile for native Android apps (ARM)
#

    ARCH        =   arm
    CPU         =   armv7-a
    VER         =   19
    NDK_ROOT    =   /usr/local/packages/android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle


    TARGET      =   hello

    SRC         =   hello.c

    DEFINES     =   

    INCLUDES    =   -I$(NDK_ROOT)/platforms/android-$(VER)/arch-$(ARCH)/usr/include

    CFLAGS      =   -march=$(CPU) \
                    -fPIE -std=c99 -Os -g \
                    $(INCLUDES) \
                    $(DEFINES)

    CXXFLAGS    =   -march=$(CPU) \
                    -fPIE -Os -g \
                    $(INCLUDES) \
                    $(DEFINES)

    ASFLAGS     =   -march=$(CPU) \
                    -fpie -Os -g \
                    $(INCLUDES) \
                    $(DEFINES)

    LDFLAGS     =   -march=$(CPU) \
                    -fpie -pie \
                    --sysroot=$(NDK_ROOT)/platforms/android-$(VER)/arch-$(ARCH)

    LOADLIBES   =   
    OBJ         :=  $(subst .c,.o,$(subst .s,.o,$(subst .cc,.o,$(SRC))))

    PFX         =   $(NDK_ROOT)/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-
    CC          =   $(PFX)gcc
    CXX         =   $(PFX)g++
    AS          =   $(PFX)as
    LD          =   $(PFX)ld
    OBJDUMP     =   $(PFX)objdump
    OBJCOPY     =   $(PFX)objcopy

all:    $(TARGET)


$(TARGET):  $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LOADLIBES)

clean:
    $(RM) $(TARGET) $(OBJ)
```